# Any Way to make Canon LBP2900B Printer work on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty?

Tags: 17.04, canon

I have tried installing capt drivers(v2.71) from official canon page. Somehow it doesn't work. Anyone found any way/solutions (either official or unofficial) to make this printer work in Zesty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so there are 4 steps:
1) install drivers
2) Register the printer (PPD) with the print spooler
3) Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file.
4) Start ccpd daemon

I wonder if you did all those; would you like detailed instructions? and what does `dpkg -l cndrvcups*` give in a terminal please; if you can copy and paste back what you get in the terminal please

---

1) if we assume the drivers got installed ... then ..if you copy this next command and paste into a terminal: open the terminal with three keys control, alt and t held down ... and to paste, right-click at the text prompt and look for PASTE in the menu that appears .....

2)**Register the printer** `sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP2900 -P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP2900CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E`

3) **Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file** .. *this assumes you have only one printer; the LBP2900 connected by usb cable* ..`sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP2900 -o /dev/usb/lp0`

4) **Start ccpd daemon**  `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

...... you should now be able to print ........

Comment: Thanks very much! That worked! Atlast...... it worked... the printer worked!!!

Comment: that's great Edwin; if you turn the computer off, you need to open the terminal, and issue that last command: if you press the up arrow key on your keyboard, it should bring that command up for you to run `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`   .. I will look for the automate trick but I will post this comment for the meanwhile; many thanks for letting us know it works