# canon LPB6000 installed on ubuntu 17.4 but doesn't work?

Tags: printing

Hy friends. I'm a beginner in Linux, I was on windows so I'm completely lost ! I can't find where is the problem with the printer installation ! After 3 days of research on Internet I finally could install canon LBP6000, it appear on printer localhost but doesn't print the job !!!
I need an answer please cause I don't wanna come back to windows I've a report to achieve.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide more details please

Answer (score 1):

I have the same printer and I had the same problem. On Xubuntu 18.04, I resolved it this way.

1) First, allow compatibility with needed i386 libraries (although drivers are labelled as 64bit, they depend on them). Enter the following

```
sudo sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libstdc++6:i386 libxml2:i386 zlib1g:i386 libpopt0:i386
sudo apt-get install libglade2-0:amd64
```

2) Install drivers as explained by pdc.

3) Register the printer

```
sudo lpadmin -p LBP6000 -m CNCUPSLBP6018CAPTS.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787
```

Note that the port here must be the same as in `UI PORT` (see the screenshot in the second answer by pdc). Then

```
lpadmin -p LBP6000 -E
```

(I guess you can also give a combined command, as suggested by pdc.)

4) Register the printer in the ccpd deamon:

```
sudo ccpdadmin -p LBP6000 -o /dev/usb/lp0
```

Of course, change `/dev/usb/lp0` with the right path if needed.

5) Start the ccpd deamon

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start
```

Connect the printer and check its status typing

```
sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd status
```

You should see two numbers in the output. If not, type `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd restart`.

6) Try to print a test page from Settings>Printers. If the printer is still silent, type

```
captstatusui -P LBP6000 -e
```

to start Canon's printer monitor. Now the printer should work.

7) Perhaps you want ccpd and the printer monitor automatically start on boot. For the first one, type

```
sudo update-rc.d ccpd defaults
```

Next, you may run command at point 6) going to Settings>Startup or following, for instance, [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228304/how-do-i-run-a-script-at-start-up).

**Remark.** If the printer return silent on reboot, try to restart ccpd and captstatusui. You may also try to power off and on the printer. That worked for me.

Comment: I had the same issue with my LPB6000 on Debian 10 and can confirm that the answer provided by @Federico resolved the problem. The only part that in his solution did not work was the -E switch at point 3. So, I dropped it and then did `cupsenable LBP6000` and `cupsaccept LBP6000`. The printer is working now.

Answer (score 0):

so this printer needs Canon's CAPT driver; which they update regularly; this post from yesterday on this forum is about the same CAPT driver; [Any Way to make Canon LBP2900B Printer work on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/933124/any-way-to-make-canon-lbp2900b-printer-work-on-ubuntu-17-04-zesty) so have a read as it is very similar to yours; please delete any setup for your LBP6000 from the PRINTERS folder; if it does not work ... **I assume you have 64bit install** ..

so there are 4 steps to get it working:

1) **install drivers**; you need the latest drivers from here http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html as they were issued 15th May 2017; SAVE as you download it and it should end up in your Downloads folder; then issue the following commands; by copying them; and pasting them one by one into a terminal; hit the ENTER key after each paste ..

`cd Downloads`

`tar -zxvf linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz`

`cd linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian`

`sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-common_3.21-1_amd64.deb`

and then  `sudo dpkg -i cndrvcups-capt_2.71-1_amd64.deb` and drivers now installed ...

2) **register the printer** again, please copy this and paste it into the terminal ..copy it all .. it is a long string of data ...

`sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP6000 -P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP6018CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E`

3) **Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file**

`sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP6000 -o /dev/usb/lp0`

4) **Start ccpd daemon**

`sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

at that point, your printer should print: **please post back and tell us how things are**: please, please ..!!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but : when I execute the 2nd step (register the printer) I get this : "Printer name can only contain printable characters". And when I execute the 3rd step (Register the printer in the ccpd daemon setup file) I get this : "can't find in cups Spooler entry". And the printer doesn't show in Printers-localhost !

Comment: Here what I get :  http://hpics.li/f876ebf

Comment: so there's problems at the very beginning: so if you open a terminal and type `cd Downloads` and hit ENTER; and then type `ls`, that is asking for a list of what is in that Downloads directory; so do you see linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz .. or, better still, linux-capt-drv-v271-uken    ...let's just start there;

Comment: Merci beaucoup :) Thanks a lot for your help. When I type ls I get linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz in red :  http://hpics.li/115ac40

Comment: Bonjour Leila; you have an old version of the CAPT driver (2.7); go to the Canon Asia link in the answer above (where I say install drivers): get the latest; then the commands should work .. so download the latest and then carry out all the commands in the install drivers instructions

Comment: Bonsoir pdc :) I did that yesterday, I installed linux-capt-drv-v271-uken.tar.gz from the link http://support-asia.canon-asia.com/contents/ASIA/EN/0100459601.html. I'll delete all present folder about capt-drv and I'll install it again, then I'll try again your commands, I hope that will work. Merci !

Comment: oh I am sorry; I am getting confused between the ufr driver; that is 3.1 and the capt; that is 2.7; my apologies; if you open a terminal; and do `cd Downloads` and then `cd linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/` and do `ls` then it should show 64-bit_Driver so do `cd 64-bit_Driver` and do `ls`and it should show Debian; so do `cd Debian` and then you can do the commands to install the two drivers

Comment: Bonsoir... when I run this command :                                                     lapaix@paix:~/Downloads/linux-capt-drv-v271-uken/64-bit_Driver/Debian$ sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP6000 -p /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP6018CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E
  I get this :   lpadmin: Printer name can only contain printable characters.    :(  Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: if we try `sudo /usr/sbin/lpadmin -p LBP6000 -P /usr/share/cups/model/CNCUPSLBP6018CAPTK.ppd -v ccp://localhost:59787 -E`            ......best copy with your mouse what is there, and PASTE into the terminal; right-click in the terminal to get a menu and select the PASTE that appears ...... you will see I have changed a small-case p to a capital P ..

Comment: Hi again... When I replace p to a capital P it works and the printer is installed but also no responding !!! it doesn't print any thing even the test page !!!!  :(

Comment: so it is a usb printer; it is the only printer connected to the computer, is it? that is very important;            and you did the 3rd step of `sudo /usr/sbin/ccpdadmin -p LBP6000 -o /dev/usb/lp0`and also the final step of turning on the ccpd daemon which is `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start`

Comment: Merci beaucoup for your answers but the same !!! it doesn't work :(((((((

Comment: Here what I get processing without response ! http://hpics.li/1ae7725

Comment: if you turn the computer off; you need to do `sudo /etc/init.d/ccpd start` each time you start it;         but let's go back and check from the beginning and what does `dpkg -l cndrvcups*` give if you paste in a terminal; (copy the command); after that if we get you to open your PRINTERS folder; delete all that is in there for the LBP; and then one by one copy commands 2) and 3) and 4) into the terminal; hit ENTER key and move to the next command please;

Comment: salut !  when I put the command dpkg -l cndrvcups*   I get this http://hpics.li/a532269    . I've deleted LPB present printer then I copied commands 2) and 3) and 4) into the terminal and yes of course I used ENTER key to move to the next command :P here the result http://hpics.li/fef91a2     but the same whene I want to print test page no response !!!!!!!!  :,(((((((

Comment: thanks for the two screenshots; I see a reference to LBP6020 in the second shot: do you have an LBP6020 also please? (connected by usb?)

Comment: no I've only lbp 6000 but after installation I get both !!!! and yes my lbp 6000 is connected by usb

Comment: I confirm that the instructions works perfectly for LPB6000B on Ubuntu 20.04.
Thanks.

Comment: To enable the service and avoid manually starting it. Add this thes lines ```### BEGIN INIT INFO
# startup script for Canon Printer Daemon for CUPS (ccpd)
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
### END INIT INFO```
 to 
```/etc/init.d/ccpd ```
Then start the service by running ```sudo service ccpd start```

Answer (score 0):

[image]the command `sudo ccpdadmin` asks for the status of the ccpdadmin so please see how ours appears: we have 2 usb printers: the first is allocated to /usb/lp0 and the second, the LBP, is allocated to /usb/lp1 and if you have 2 printers on your usb, then if the LBP6000 is the second in the rankings, then it needs to be lp1

Comment: I'll delete again all printers that appear in  Printers-localhost then I'll do the commands from the beginning.  Thanks 6000 times for your help :)

Comment: I can only hope it works; I have now done a couple of 64bit installs and they are fine; and I have advised others; it perplexes me what is your problem;